# Alignment of buttons flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter app and I want to align those buttons in the centre , but I don't know how or what to used. I already use positioned but I think is wrong , any idea? Should I use a sized box or Alignment ? or should I wrap them in something else? should I delete just *left : 85 *?

```
 Positioned(
              top: 600,
              left: 85,
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CountDownTimer()),
                  );
                },
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80.0)),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                child: Ink(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: [Colors.white, Colors.white30],
                        begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        end: Alignment.centerRight,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                  child: Container(
                    constraints:
                        BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 250.0, minHeight: 50.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(
                      "Start playing",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )),
          Positioned(
            top: 700,
            left: 85,
            child: Container(
              height: 60,
              width: 240,
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80.0)),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                child: Ink(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: [Colors.black, Colors.black87],
                        begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        end: Alignment.centerRight,
                      ),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                  child: Container(
                    constraints:
                        BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 250.0, minHeight: 50.0),
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(
                      "Spotify Playlist",
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

By Center, I take it you are using a Stack to contain these buttons?
In that case do not use Position, unless you need to add Absolute Positioning after Centering the buttons. So in your case do this:

```
     Align(
alignment: Alignment.center,
child: Positioned(
                  top: 600,
                  left: 85,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CountDownTimer()),
                      );
                    },
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80.0)),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                    child: Ink(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: [Colors.white, Colors.white30],
                            begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            end: Alignment.centerRight,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                      child: Container(
                        constraints:
                            BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 250.0, minHeight: 50.0),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text(
                          "Start playing",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 15),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ))),
     Align(
alignment: Alignment.center,
child:Positioned(
                top: 700,
                left: 85,
                child: Container(
                  height: 60,
                  width: 240,
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80.0)),
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                    child: Ink(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                            colors: [Colors.black, Colors.black87],
                            begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            end: Alignment.centerRight,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                      child: Container(
                        constraints:
                            BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 250.0, minHeight: 50.0),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Text(
                          "Spotify Playlist",
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )),
```

Basically your widgets (buttons) will first be centered on the Parent Widget (your Stack), then the Position Widgets will be used to adjust the absolute coordinates of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap all of this inside a Stack widget, not a column. Stack widgets allow Align and Positioned children.

Alternatively, if you want to center them

- horizontally, you can wrap them in a column and use
  `crossAxisAlignment = CrossAxisAlignment.center`.
- vertically, you can wrap them in a column and use `mainAxisAlignment = MainAxisAlignment.center`.